# How to push to github wiki without username and password?

Tags: github

I've succeeded to config to pull/push from my github repo without username and password using ssh-key.

But I cannot find a way to pull/push wiki for that repo without username and password.

Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you take the clone of your wiki separately?

Comment: yep, I cloned it with github given url. I could pull/push into it also but it requires an username/password. What i'm asking for is how to push to wiki repo without username/password. I generated and added public key to my github account already.

Comment: You just need to clone it using the `ssh` link. Check the answer.

Comment: Were you able to ssh clone the wiki repo? It worked for me without issues.

Answer (score 4):

Wikis are just Git repositories, you can make changes locally and push them to your repository. But you have to clone it separately.

Append `.wiki.git` to the repository name.

That is, if your repository name was foobar:

```
git clone git@github.com:myusername/foobar.git
```

would be the path to clone your repository and

```
git clone git@github.com:myusername/foobar.wiki.git
```

would be the path to clone its wiki.

Also you can search the clone link on the wiki page on the bottom right side with heading:

**Clone this wiki locally**

[image]

Here you will find the `https` clone link just change it to `ssh` clone link it will get cloned to your local and you can update the repo from your local.

This should be the format for the ssh link:

```
git@<host>:<username>/<repo_name>.wiki.git
```

Once you have cloned the wiki, you can add new files, edit existing ones, and commit your changes. You and your collaborators can create branches when working on wikis, but only changes pushed to the master branch will be made live and available to your readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access set up and GitHub normally shows you the SSH URL for repos, it will still show you the HTTPS URL for Wiki repos, so you have to manually convert to the SSH URL format before you can push using SSH credentials.