# Is it possible to access a Github Wiki via SSH?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I just created a Wiki for a Github repo, and cloned it to my desktop. There is only the option to clone using `https`, which means every time I try to push `git` asks me for my username and password.

Is there some way to use SSH in a Github Wiki as I do with all my standard repos?

I checked the [Wiki help](https://help.github.com/categories/wiki/) but couldn't find anything there.

---

I' using 2FA in Github by the way.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can also clone wiki via ssh :

```
git clone git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.wiki.git
```

Comment: Thank you Bertrand! That was easier than I thought. Not sure why Github does not show that option along with `https`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git clone ssh://git@github.com/[YOUR_USERNAME_OR_ORGANIZATION]/[YOUR_REPO].wiki.git`? I edited the original answer to be that now.

Comment: honestly, `ssh://` is optional, but the url must be of the form `git@github.com:org/repo.wiki.git`

Comment: FWIW, the git clone command fails for me unless I include the ssh. The following was the only thing that worked for me: `ssh://git@github.com/[YOUR_USERNAME_OR_ORGANIZATION]/[YOUR_REPO].wiki.git`

Comment: the option without ssh:// works for me, the one with ssh:// doesn't. But the problem is that even after cloning through ssh I am still asked for my login and pwd every time. My public ssh key is registered on github, and so that is not the problem. Any thoughts on what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: @RicardoPietrobon that's because on github site displays https, not ssh, here explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945548/how-to-push-to-github-wiki-without-username-and-password