# How to push to a github Wiki repo using ssh?

Tags: github, ssh, https, wiki

There is a previous post on how to [clone a GitHub wiki using ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493135/is-it-possible-to-access-a-github-wiki-via-ssh/42493214), and that works just fine. The problem is that after cloning, I need to add my login and password every time I push. The latter sounds like https to me. The question then is: after cloning a wiki page from GitHub that I own, how can I use ssh so that it doesn't ask me for my login and password every time?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-git

Comment: @xiawi yes it does, thanks a ton